# Is it possible to create a spreadsheet from a chart Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016

Exactly as the title says, is it possible to take a chart from say, Word, and then create a spreadsheet of its data in Excel. Specifically, I am asking in regards to 2016 for both.

For a bit of context, if it helps in any way. I lost the spreadsheet with the data for a Gantt Chart and didn't have any backups. However, I had it in a word document as an imported chart, not an image.

Comment: Just to be clear: you're asking if Excel has a way to dynamically interpret visually-represented data into tabular data?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. This function is not implemented in either of these programs.